# Where to configure SSL in micro service architecture

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, architecture, microservices, kubernetes-ingress

I need to convert monothic application to micro service architecture. Few suggestion/confirmation are required before i finalize the design.

I will be using docker containers and kubernetes. Structure will be like this

[image]

Ingress -> Zuul API Gateway--> Microservice 
             -> Angular PODS

- Ingress Router to route traffic to
- Angular PODS where angular code will be present
- API Gateway Zuul API Gateway where we will perform Authorization and
  Authentication

So my doubt is, for inter service communication do we need to configure SSL ?

Comment: Will you be using GKE, AKS or standalone installation?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of security you need for inter-service communication. If that is required, I would recommend to use service mesh for the same. It will give mutual TLS for your services and many other benefits. Istio (https://istio.io/) is the most widely used service mesh.